# Append SQL columns based on different JOINs

Tags: sql

My problem is I have a table where I want to return a column from an SQL database as two different columns based on different JOIN conditions.

My two select statements:

My first statement returns the check numbers and amounts for all of our checks that have gone through the process of being deposited -> and then ipaced (just a term).

```
SELECT COURTESY_CHECK.CHECK_NUMBER,
COURTESY_CHECK.CHECK_AMOUNT, 
CHECK_DEPOSIT.ID AS DEPOSIT_ID
FROM COURTESY_CHECK
INNER JOIN CHECK_DEPOSIT ON CHECK_DEPOSIT.COURTESY_CHECK_ID = COURTESY_CHECK.ID
INNER JOIN DEPOSIT ON CHECK_DEPOSIT_ID = DEPOSIT.ID 
INNER JOIN IPAC ON DEPOSIT.ID = IPAC.DEPOSIT_ID
```

My second statement returns the check numbers and amounts of the checks that have just been deposited.

```
SELECT COURTESY_CHECK.CHECK_NUMBER, 
COURTESY_CHECK.CHECK_AMOUNT, 
CHECK_DEPOSIT.ID AS DEPOSIT_ID 
FROM COURTESY_CHECK
INNER JOIN CHECK_DEPOSIT ON CHECK_DEPOSIT.COURTESY_CHECK_ID = COURTESY_CHECK.ID
```

I would like to have a table like

```
IPAC/DEPOSITED AMOUNT   DEPOSITED AMOUNT  CHECK_NUMBER
---------------------   ----------------  ------------
$4.00                                      123456
                        $5.00              654321
```

I'm using BIRT to compile reports and it really only allows you to chart data based on single data sets (which is a single query) AFAIK. I'd like to chart the total "IPAC/Deposited" amount versus the "Deposited" amount.

Comment: `INNER JOIN IPAC ON DEPOSIT.ID = IPAC.DEPOSIT_ID` should've been `INNER JOIN IPAC ON CHECK_DEPOSIT.IPAC_ID = IPAC.ID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're really close. Wouldn't a UNION query do the trick? Something like this:

```
SELECT COURTESY_CHECK.CHECK_NUMBER,
COURTESY_CHECK.CHECK_AMOUNT AS [IPAC AMOUNT], 
null AS [DEPOSITED AMOUNT],
CHECK_DEPOSIT.ID AS DEPOSIT_ID
FROM COURTESY_CHECK
INNER JOIN CHECK_DEPOSIT ON CHECK_DEPOSIT.COURTESY_CHECK_ID = COURTESY_CHECK.ID
INNER JOIN DEPOSIT ON CHECK_DEPOSIT_ID = DEPOSIT.ID 
INNER JOIN IPAC ON DEPOSIT.ID = IPAC.DEPOSIT_ID 

UNION

SELECT COURTESY_CHECK.CHECK_NUMBER, null AS [IPAC AMOUNT],
COURTESY_CHECK.CHECK_AMOUNT AS [DEPOSITED AMOUNT], 
CHECK_DEPOSIT.ID AS DEPOSIT_ID 
FROM COURTESY_CHECK
INNER JOIN CHECK_DEPOSIT ON CHECK_DEPOSIT.COURTESY_CHECK_ID = COURTESY_CHECK.ID
```

Edit ... this CASE statement with outer joins might be more efficient -- I think this would work, too:

```
SELECT COURTESY_CHECK.CHECK_NUMBER,
CASE WHEN IPAC.DEPOSIT_ID IS NOT NULL THEN COURTESY_CHECK.CHECK_AMOUNT 
ELSE NULL END AS [IPAC AMOUNT],
CASE WHEN IPAC.DEPOSIT_ID IS NOT NULL THEN NULL ELSE COURTESY_CHECK.CHECK_AMOUNT
END AS [DEPOSITED AMOUNT],
CHECK_DEPOSIT.ID AS DEPOSIT_ID
FROM COURTESY_CHECK
INNER JOIN CHECK_DEPOSIT ON CHECK_DEPOSIT.COURTESY_CHECK_ID = COURTESY_CHECK.ID
LEFT JOIN DEPOSIT ON CHECK_DEPOSIT_ID = DEPOSIT.ID 
LEFT JOIN IPAC ON DEPOSIT.ID = IPAC.DEPOSIT_ID
```

Comment: actually, a CASE statement will be more efficient . . . hold on, working on it...

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! I knew about the `UNION` operator, but it was concatenating the columns not appending them. switching out null for columns appends them?

Comment: I didn't try your `CASE` example yet, but am willing to learn more about it. Thanks for the alternative.